# Matlab: When implementing methods declared abstract in the super class, why must access be public?

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance

In Matlab (2017a), subclasses cannot restrict access to inherited methods that are declared abstract in the abstract superclass. Why wouldn't this be allowed? A small example:

super.m

```
classdef (Abstract) super
    methods (Abstract)
        out = fun(obj,in)
    end
end
```

sub.m

```
classdef sub < super
    properties
        prop
    end
    methods (Access='private') %remove the access restriction to run without errors
        function out = fun(obj,in)
            out = obj.prop * in;
        end
    end
end
```

testInheritance.m

```
instance = sub;
```

Execution of testInheritance.m results in the following error message:

> Error using sub Method 'fun' in class 'sub' uses different access
>   permissions than its superclass 'super'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have to be public, but they have to be accessible by the sub and super class, and as the error states they must be the same. So you've got 2 issues:

1. Your super class's method is public and your sub class's method is private
2. You cannot just set the super class's method to private, or the sub class has no visibility of it.

You want to set `Access = protected`, which means only the super class and sub classes have visibility of the function, therefore the have the same access permissions, can specify their own behaviour and the function is hidden from other objects.

Here are the `Access` options, with definitions from the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-attributes.html):

- public — Unrestricted access
- protected — Access from methods in class **or subclasses**
- private — Access by class methods only (**not from subclasses**)

---

So your classes become:

```
classdef (Abstract) super
    methods (Abstract = true, Access = protected)
        out = fun(obj,in)
    end
end

classdef sub < super
    properties
        prop
    end
    methods (Access = protected) 
        function out = fun(obj,in)
            out = obj.prop * in;
        end
    end
end
```

Note that the syntax is `Access = protected`, not `Access = 'protected'` as you showed.

Comment: Thanks. I failed to realize the super class method was public, because I didn't think of an abstract method as having any access property.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the access properties of a method that is declared `'public'` in the base class to make it not accessible in the derived class (which is what your code is attempting to do) is not permitted because it would violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

In other words, by changing the method `fun` from `public` to `private`, then a client cannot use an instance of `sub` as if it was an instance of `super`.